# Memcache Vs MongoDB for auto-complete

Tags: mongodb, memcached

We have RDBMS which also runs our auto-complete queries. I'm planning to reduce the load on RDBMS by re-directing auto-complete queries to MongoDB. The other option I have is use Memcache. The SQL queries are of nature "where lastName like 'abc%'. Can I query Memcache with Like clause? Also, my data will also be updated frequently so if I use Memcache, it needs to stay updated accordingly. Can anyone suggest if Memcache or any other cache is better over NoSQL? What are the advantages, if any, of using cache in this case and which one is preferred approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue. Memcache is not the correct tool to do this as the data on Memcache is not persistent. And the number of permutations eventually become so huge that it does not make sense storing so much of data to Memcache.

We are using elasticsearch to handle auto suggest queries. It is extremely fast. It gives us most of the results in under 5ms.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

You can Refer this link.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Did you use Elaticsearch on top of Oracle?

Comment: No, we created documents for autosuggest in elasticsearch itself. The data in elasticsearch will be a subset of what is there in the Oracle database. So we synced data to ES and ran the queries from there.